# How do I Linq Select Multiple properties of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that are in the order that I want to select them, but not sure how to do it...

For example, if I have `List<obj> mylist`

where `obj` has properties:

```
start,
end
```

How do I create a list of numbers that contains

```
start1, end1, start2, end2, start3, end3, etc...
```

where start1, end1 are the int properties from the first object, start2, end2 are the number properties from the second object, and so on.. I know how to do this in a foreach loop, but not sure how to do so in Linq.

Comment: The answer below is absolutely right but if you're at all interested in performance I'd go ahead and do this in a for loop. The Linq approach requires allocating and copying a new array for every member. All that is not without overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, this is a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-8.0). Something along these lines:

```cs
var result = mylist
    .SelectMany(o => new[] { o.start, o.end })
    .ToList();
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj2IIE4AKAIkB4NwEH3uASha48ANwCGYUmACmAZwgAbYKQC8pKHIDuAbQC6pAN5bdJ0guDS1mzDFJyocDaQKkAvg+06LVm64ALOgOTi6aAOxRnp54AJCUAMpyynIAxsAAspJQAJ6cAPYaAHxm+kamBZT+YMAOVWGeQvGUACoFdFacIqy48kqqlACSUAoADunA3UxAA===)